# Program which will edit all items in my contact list using Python on s60

Tags: python, symbian, nokia, s60

I want to write a program on Python, which will edit my contact list on NOKIA 5730 XM, for example a number starts with 8xxxxxxxx and I want it to become 5xxxxxxxx. Is it possible, and if yes, can you help me to write it ?

Comment: It would help us if you give us some more information. How do you access the contact information? If you simply have them as strings, and you only need to make that change which you asked for, all you need to do is `phone_number[0] = '5'`